# Using fermats little theorem to find all x

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> The question tasks me to find all x such that
> $2^x \equiv  1 \pmod{7}$.

By inspection I can see that $x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ but is there a way to show this using Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: To start off, what does Fermat's little theorem tell you about multiplication $\pmod{7}$?

Comment: See the Theorem in the linked dupe.